# Do I have to free an array inside a struct?

Tags: c, memory, struct

If I have a struct:

```
struct Rec
{
    uint16_t vals[500];
};


Rec * prec = malloc(sizeof(Rec));
//Rec * prec = (Rec *) malloc(sizeof(Rec)); This code was my original and is incorrect.
//                                          See Below for details.

// initialize everything in vals
```

Will this code suffice to free all memory used?

```
free(prec);
```

Or do I have to `free` the array separately?

Comment: `prec` currently doesn't point _to_ anything. You're missing the most important part of your code: how you allocate an object of type `struct Rec`. Show us that.

Comment: @sarnold `Rec * prec = (Rec *) malloc(sizeof(Rec));` From what I have gathered below, a `free` is necessary on `prec`, as it was malloc'ed, but not on `vals`.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles/112966#112966

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will suffice.
You did not allocate the array separately, so just freeing the allocated pointer shall suffice.

Follow the Rule:
You should only call `free` on address returned to you by `malloc`, anything else will result in **Undefined Behavior**.

References:
**c99 Standard: 7.20.3.2 The `free` function**

> **Synopsis**
>      #include 
>   void free(void *ptr);
>
> **Description:**
>    The `free` function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. **Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the `calloc`, `malloc`,or
>   `realloc` function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`,
>   the behavior is undeﬁned**.
>
> **Returns**
>    The `free` function returns no value.

Answer (score 7):

In their earlier answers, tekknolagi and Als are both correct.  If you try executing this code snippet, it might help illuminate what is happening.

```
// cc -o test test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct rec {
    uint16_t vals[500];
};

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("struct rec is %ld bytes.\n", sizeof(struct rec));

    struct rec* rec_p = (struct rec*)malloc(sizeof(struct rec));
    free(rec_p);
}
```

When you execute this code, you will see:

```
struct rec is 1000 bytes.
```

You called `malloc` only once.  That call allocated all the space described by your structure definition.  The matching `free` likewise frees up all of this memory.

Answer (score 5):

You only use `free` when you use `malloc` (or a NULL pointer)

Meaning, it will automatically be freed on exit.

---

If you have `malloc`ed for that, then it will suffice.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> Rec * prec = (Rec *) malloc(sizeof(Rec));
> ```

Thanks for including the allocation in the comments (I edited it into the question, hope I got it right).

To free memory allocated with `malloc(3)`, you do use `free(3)`, as you've surmised.

But note that you do not need to use the `(Rec *)` case with `malloc(3)` if you `#include <stdlib.h>`. The function prototype provided in the header lets the compiler figure out the casts for you. Include the header and remove the cast.

Comment: And in fact casting the result of `malloc()` can hide errors in some cases.

Comment: I didn't know that re. stdlib. Thanks for the tip and for clarifying my question